# Referencing stylesheets in a MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, html, css, webforms

How would I go about adding a link to a stylesheet in a MasterPage?

Here is the directory sturcture of my website:

```
> MasterPages
  - Site.master
> Styles
  - Site.css
> Default.aspx
> Admin
  - Admin.aspx
```

If I add a reference to my stylesheet in the MasterPage as:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css" />
```

Everything works well in Default.aspx. But if I use the same MasterPage for the Admin.aspx page, the stylesheet cannot be found because it is looking in the wrong directory. How would I go about this? I've tried putting runat="server" in the stylehseet reference, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Why would you use the same master page for the admin? Usually you use an admin masterpage with its own css and scripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify a non ambiguous / non current relative path:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/Site.css" />
```

Answer (score 4):

This should help:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/Site.css" />
```

or (without the "~")

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/Site.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

different direction, make use of themes. add the `App_Themes` folder to your project, change theme name from "Theme1" to something more logical (usually your project name) and in the `web.config` you place this

```
<system.web>
      <pages theme="myThemeName">
      </pages>
</system.web>
```

any css or skins you place in this theme will be applied to all your pages